# Getting a MAX using AVERAGEIFS logic

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a table of data that I want to find a MAX value for.

The challenge is filtering the values I care about.

Basically, I want the MAX from Column D when:

- Column A = 'VIC'
- Column B = 'CBD'
- Column C = 'Leaderboard'

Is there a MAXIFS equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built in function for this, but you can achieve what you want with an array formula.

You enter it as:

```
=MAX(IF(A1:A20="VIC",IF(B1:B20="CBD",IF(C1:C20="Leaderboard",D1:D20))))
```

and then commit it using CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER rather than just ENTER. This will add {} around the formula and turn it into an array formula

Comment: you da man! I've never used teh {} before - how does it change the statement?

Comment: Basically, it turns it into what you wanted. They take a bit of getting your head around - see here for a starter: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-HA010228458.aspx